# Caching will not disable after updating to 1.3.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot

After upgrading from 1.2.7 our css and js in /static/ is being cached. We have set the following configuration

```
spring.messages.cache-seconds=0
spring.resources.chain.cache=false
spring.resources.chain.enabled=false
spring.resources.cache-period=0
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

Our front end is being built via gulp. With 1.2.7 any javascript changes would be seen by spring. On 1.3.0 the old file version is still being served.

Is there a setting in 1.3.0 that I missed or is this a bug?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.3-Release-Notes#spring-bootrun-resources) might be relevant, but it's impossible to say for sure as you haven't described how you're building and running the app

Comment: We are using gradle to build. I did try using `spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths` to have dev-tools watch for changes. All this did was restart the app server *without* updating the css/js being served from the static folder.

Comment: You were correct. I needed to update the gradle configuration. Thx!